# Ignore String Between Two RegEx Matches

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6, greasemonkey

I have the following RegEx:

`/Name:\s+(.*)\s+Company:\s+(.*)\s+Email:\s+(.*)\s+Phone:\s+(.*)\s+Inquiry:\s+(.*)\s+Comments:\s+(.*)/g`

I am testing it against the following which matches:

```
Name: London Brown
Company: Amazon.com
Email: london@example.com
Phone: 2065550000
Inquiry: Technical
Comments: Example comment
```

I would like to modify this RegExp to ignore "Inquiry: Technical" whether it's present in the string or not as this data is sometimes present and sometimes isn't. Such that, the following will also be accepted:

```
Name: London Brown
Company: Amazon.com
Email: london@example.com
Phone: 2065550000
Comments: Example comment
```

Since this is a greasemonkey script, I have no control over the source data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use an optional non capturing group `(?:Inquiry:\s+(.*)\s+)?`

For example

```
Name:\s+(.*)\s+Company:\s+(.*)\s+Email:\s+(.*)\s+Phone:\s+(.*)\s+(?:Inquiry:\s+(.*)\s+)?Comments:\s+(.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tLGYJz/2)

Comment: @BrockAdams That is correct, I used it to highlight all the capturing groups for the OP. I have updated the link.